# How to map # to , when `,` is my leader?

Tags: key-bindings

My leader is `,`:

```
let mapleader = ','
```

Now, I want to map `#` to find previous match (when using `f`, `F`, `t`, `T`), I try this:

```
nnoremap # ,
```

But nothing happens when I use `#`, obviously something is wrong. What would be the correct way to create the mapping I want?

UPDATE: with vim -u NONE it works fine for me too, so it must be some setting/plugin I use. Strange, cause

```
map #
```

returns this:

```
n #       * ,
```

the same thing that is returned in vim -u NONE, so it sounds like the map is ok...Strange

Thanks

Comment: Hm, this seems to work for me? When you use `nnoremap`, you always map the original built-in Vim meaning of the right-hand-side, so I see no reason why this shouldn't work...

Comment: This works for me too, maybe try using `vim -u NONE` to see if any of your plugins are causing issues

Comment: This worked for me also, I noticed that both `,` and `#` can be used now to find the previous match.

Comment: Perhaps you also have another 2-letter mapping that starts with `#`, and infinite timeout length? In this case, when you press `#`, vim will wait for the second letter, indefinitely.